# Moving between tabs inside conditional panels with rintrojs

Tags: r, shiny, intro.js

I am building an intro for a shiny app using `{rintrojs}`, but on the final step which involves moving from a `tabPanel` in one `conditionalPanel` into another `tabPanel` in a different `conditionalPanel`, the intro box ends up in the top left rather than on the tab, seemingly because it is not yet rendered, despite moving between the panels using `onbeforechange` as advised in [Multi page intro.js with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545002/multi-page-intro-js-with-shiny) .

```
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- tagList(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("h1 {font-size: 72px;} hr {height: 300px}"))),
    introjsUI(),
    navbarPage("Demo", id = 'tabs', windowTitle = "demo",
      tabPanel(value = "fTab", "First tab"),
      tabPanel(value = "sTab", "Second tab")
      ),
  tags$div(
    class = "container-fluid",
    fluidRow(
  wellPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        "input.tabs == 'fTab'",
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(id = "fChild1", "First child1", hr(), h1("Tab1, Child1"),
          actionButton("startButton", "Help"),
          ),
        tabPanel(id = "fChild2", "First child2", hr(), h1("Tab1, Child2")),
        ),
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        "input.tabs == 'sTab'",
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(id = "sChild1", "Second child1", hr(), h1("Tab2, Child1")),
          tabPanel(id = "sChild2", "Second child2", hr(), h1("Tab2, Child2"))
        )
      )
    )
      ))
)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    intro_steps <- data.frame(
      element=c("a[data-value=\"sTab\"]",
                "a[data-value=\"fTab\"]",
                "a[data-value=\"First child2\"]",
                "a[data-value=\"Second child2\"]"
                ),
      intro=c("first thing",
              "then this",
              "more stuff",
              "and finally")
    )

    observeEvent(input$startButton, {
      introjs(
        session,
        options = list(steps=intro_steps),
        events = list(onbeforechange = I("
        if (this._currentStep == 0) {
        $('a[data-value=\"fTab\"]').removeClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"sTab\"]').addClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"sTab\"]').trigger('click');
        }
        if (this._currentStep == 1) {
        $('a[data-value=\"sTab\"]').removeClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"fTab\"]').addClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"fTab\"]').trigger('click');
        }
        if (this._currentStep == 2) {
        $('a[data-value=\"First child2\"]').addClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"First child2\"]').trigger('click');
        }
        if (this._currentStep == 3) {
        $('a[data-value=\"fTab\"]').removeClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"sTab\"]').addClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"sTab\"]').trigger('click');
        $('a[data-value=\"Second child2\"]').addClass('active');
        $('a[data-value=\"Second child2\"]').trigger('click');
        }
        "))
      )

    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `navbarPage`'s  `title` parameter is not optional. Try `navbarPage("App Title", id = 'tabs', windowTitle = "demo", ...` regarding your first comment.